# laravel eloquent relationship using "with", "whereHas" and "whereIn" clauses

Tags: laravel, octobercms, laravel-query-builder

I have a model "Project" that belongsToMany `sites` and each `site` belongsTo a single `Locality` and each `locality` belongsTo a single `State`.

On the other hand I have a user that belongsToMany `States`

I want to list the projects that are in the same state as the user, so ...

```
$user = Auth::getUser();
$userStates = array();

foreach($user->profile->states as $singleState){
    $userStates[] = $singleState->id;
}

Project::with(['sites','locality','state'])
->whereHas('state', function($q) use($userStates) {
    // Query the name field in status table
    $q->whereIn('id', $userStates); // '=' is optional
})
```

I am using OctoberCMS which is built on laravel, However I keep getting an error that says:

```
Call to undefined method October\Rain\Database\QueryBuilder::state()
```

Comment: Is the `state` relation added within the `Project` model?

Comment: Is the method name for state relationship actually called `state()`?

Comment: @Classified the `state` doesn't have a direct relation with the project because the project could work in different sites and that should be the determining factor in defining which state the project belongs to.

Comment: @RossWilson in octoberCMS relationships you don't need to define a method it is done as follows:-

`class Locality extends Model
{

    public $belongsTo = [
        'state' => ['Albaroody\Grants\Models\RegionState']
    ];
    public $hasMany = [
        'sites' => ['Albaroody\Grants\Models\ProjectSite', 'key'=> 'locality_id']
    ];
}
`

Comment: Ah cool, I've never used OctoberCMS but it's good to know, thanks! Glad you got your issue sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you the projects limited to the authenticated user's states:

```
$projects = Project::with(['sites.locality.state' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('id', auth()->user()->profile->states->pluck('id')->toArray());
}])->get();
```

**update**

This should not return projects without a site:

```
$projects = Project::whereHas('sites.locality.state', function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('id', auth()->user()->profile->states->pluck('id')->toArray());
}])->get();
```

Comment: I have replaced `auth()->user()` with `Auth::getUser()` and it returned a result of all the projects (even the ones where there are no sites to begin with), could it be possible to use a `has` somewhere?

Comment: Yeah `whereHas` should get you the result you're after, answer has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced whereHas with has and placed has and kept using the with and it worked... thanks a lot

Comment: What if the state was - in another scenario - a group of "states", how would I get the projects that has the same array of states as the user's array of states?